# String to a singly linked list

Tags: java, string, pointers, linked-list

I am trying to convert a string to a linked list where each digit is in a separate node.

I set on it trying to debug it but I can't seem to find what's wrong with my logic.
I keep getting a weird 2-digit number in each node and not necessarily even the digits that appear in the string.

Please note the `ListNode` is the class I create a new node object with.

```java
String number = "807";
   
int size = number.length();
int pos = 0;
ListNode dummyhead = new ListNode();
ListNode curr = dummyhead;
while (size > 0){
    curr.next = new ListNode(number.charAt(pos));   
    pos++;
    size--;
    curr = curr.next;
}

return dummyhead.next;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're on the right track. The method works fine, but it seems you are not iterating the list right. Here is how I tested your code:

```
public class ListNode{
    ListNode next;
    char data;
    public ListNode(char data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public ListNode() {}
}
```

```
private static ListNode getList(String number){
    int size = number.length();
    int pos = 0;
    ListNode dummyhead = new ListNode();
    ListNode curr = dummyhead;
    while (size > 0){
        curr.next = new ListNode(number.charAt(pos));   
        pos++;
        size--;
        curr = curr.next;
   }
   return dummyhead.next;
}
private static String printList(ListNode head) {
    ListNode n = head;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while(n != null) {
        sb.append(n.data+"-");
        n = n.next;
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String number = "807";
    System.out.println(printList(getList(number)));
}
```

Output:

```
8-0-7-
```

Answer (score 1):

`charAt` returns the character of the specified position. A `char` is a numeric type, but it represents the ascii address of the character it represents.

```
"807".charAt(0)
```

returns `56` because that is the ascii value of `8`.

I suspect that you have a `int data` field inside `ListNode`, which saves that `char` into a regular `int`.

Your "807" will thus be transformed into a list of the numbers 56, 48, 55.

You apparently want to save that `"8"` into the node, so use

```
while (size > 0){
  //for pos=0, this converts the string "8" to the integer 8:
  Integer n = Integer.valueOf(number.substring(pos, pos+1));
  curr.next = new ListNode(n);
```

Or, as Majed suggests in his answer, change the type of your `data` field inside of `ListNode` to `char`.